# Magento 2 - Cannot edit or update SKU Value

Tags: magento2, admin, sku

When I try to update SKU from the admin catalog page in Magento 2. It throws error "Validation failed" and in exception log, it shows the following error.

```
main.CRITICAL: Validation Failed {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Validation\\ValidationException(code: 0): Validation Failed at <--Root folder->/magento/module-inventory/Model/SourceItem/Command/Handler/SourceItemsSaveHandler.php:71)"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually. It is an admin configuration That needs to assign a source for inventory.

Select products
Catalog > Product > Action Dropdown > Assign Source

Comment: It is working for once. Like if I revert the sku with old one, it is not getting saved.